# VAR model terminology

Tags: time-series, multicollinearity, vector-autoregression, macroeconomics

I am currently trying to learn more about VAR models in general and have been reading Cochrane's paper on transitory GNP components which can be found here, http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/research/Papers/Cochrane%20Perm%20and%20Trans%20GNP%20and%20stocks%20(QJE).pdf

This paper is of particular interest to me as I think it relates closely to something I am working on. If anyone is familiar with this paper or cares to take a look, I'm curious as to how the inclusion of the consumption/GNP ratio would be classified as far as the overall model structure. Since the VAR model is two dimensional and does not estimate an equation for the ratio - does the ratio act as an exogenous variable? Another aspect of the ratio's inclusion that I am curious about is the issue of multi-colinearity. As the variables are all in natural logs, does including the ratio defined as the difference between the other two variables create any issues? I suspect that this is perfectly fine however I'm interested in knowing why. At first glance it seems that the ratio (difference in LN of X1 and X2) is a linear combination of the others but I am wondering if I might be misunderstanding the nature of multicolinearity - perhaps it is not just how the variable is defined but rather what type of effect it measure on the dependent.